# Import added does not appear in the Imports collection (Msbuild Project)

Tags: msbuild, microsoft.build, buildengine

This code does not write anything to the console cause the collection is empty.

```
Project p = new Project(engine);
p.AddNewImport(@"C:\mytarget.targets","");
foreach(Import imp in p.Imports)
    Console.WriteLine(p.ProjectPath);
```

But!, if I debug the code the collections get the imports, I guess it has to do with timing?

Comment: I kinda solved it with this:
p.Load(p.Xml);

ugly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call p.Load(YOUR_REQUIRED_PARAMETER) and then you can add further imports.

Cheers
Orlando

Comment: I lost this project so I cannot mark your post as answer until I try it... or you get many +1... sorry